# Rails/Phonelib: Why does my telephone number validator fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am using `PhoneLib` (https://github.com/daddyz/phonelib) to validate my phone numbers.

I have a model `Subscription` with a column `phone_number`.

I'm testing this phone number: `3052612151`.

I can see that Phonelib considers it to be a valid number:

```rb
> Phonelib.valid_for_country? "3052612151", :us
#=> true
```

However, when I use Phonelib's validator, my record is not considered to be valid.

```rb
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :phone_number, phone: { countries: :us }
```

```rb
> s = Subscription.create(phone_number: '3052612151', email: 'example@example.com')
> s.valid?
#=> false
> s.errors.full_messages
#=> ["Phone number is invalid"]
```

I've been scratching my head for over an hour. Can anyone see what I've done wrong? Why does Phonelib consider the number to be valid when calling #valid_for_country? but not when used as a validator?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is maybe you should set the default country in an initializer

```
# config/initializers/phonelib.rb
Phonelib.default_country = "US"
```

Then just use `validates :phone_number, phone: true` in your model.

Comment: Nope. Same result.

Comment: Does it work if you include the country code (i.e. prepend the number with `1` or `+1`)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `countries: [:us]`, the validator actually does a `&` operation and checks if the size is greater than 0, maybe it's expecting an array. https://github.com/daddyz/phonelib/blob/master/lib/validators/phone_validator.rb#L85

The validator actually checks 4 validations, it's a really bad design that all validations return the same error message, weird :S. https://github.com/daddyz/phonelib/blob/master/lib/validators/phone_validator.rb#L63